# Getting a list of WSUS updates for Clients with matching fields out of the AD (Powershelll)

Tags: powershell

like statted in the title, I want to get a list from the WSUS, where every clients is listed with their required updates, already installed updates, not applicable updates etc..

(Comparable to the message you can get from the WSUS, telling you which computer group need updates)

I already managed to write the necessary part to get the necessary update-count from the WSUS:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer('XXX',$true,XXXX)
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) |
        Format-Table @{L='ComputerTarget';E=$wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}},
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotApplicableCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount -Autosize
```

Now I want to add a column to which shows me the AD field 'Description' for each client.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer('XXX',$true,XXXX)
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$adusers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX" -Properties "Description","DNSHostName"
$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) |
        Format-Table @{L='ComputerTarget';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName}},
@{L='Username';E={???}},
@{L='NeededCount';E={($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)}},DownloadedCount,NotApplicableCount,NotInstalledCount,InstalledCount,FailedCount -Autosize
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: With `Get-ADComputer` you do not get user objects. So, what is it exactly you want in the report, usernames (as your `L='Username'`) sugests or the description property of the computer? (that you should be able to get using `(Get-ADComputer -Identity $wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId) -Properties Description).Description`

Comment: Hi,i want to get the description property of the computer

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion still gives me the list of computers from the wsus, but thee "username"-column is still empty